# Compute the following integral: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}\sin(\frac{x}{n})dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

Question: Compute: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}\sin(\frac{x}{n})dx$. This is from Folland's Real Analysis book.

If we can find an integrable majorant, then the integral will equal $0$, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(x/n)=0$.  We can use the Binominal Theorem to show $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n\geq 1+x+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n})x^2$, by noticing that all the terms will be positive since $x$ only takes nonnegative values, so we just "cut it off" after those couple of terms.  Next, since $|\sin x|\leq 1$, we can say $|\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^n}|\leq \frac{1}{1+x+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n})x^2}$, and $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n})x^2}<\infty$, so we have our integrable majorant, and by Dominated Convergence Theorem we can pass the limit inside the integral giving us a value of $0$.

I am curious if there are any (unseen by me) holes in this argument, or, maybe, are there any other ways of using DCT to solve this?  Thank you!

EDIT:
Just a quick note, I wanted to use Bernouli's inequality to get $\frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^n}\leq\frac{1}{1+n\frac{x}{n}}\leq\frac{1}{1+x}$... but $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x}dx$ doesn't converge.

Comment: $\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}>\frac12$ for all $n$ large enough. Hence

$$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n>1+\binom{n}{1}\frac{x}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}=1+x+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}>1+\frac{1}{4}x^2$$ Hence $\Big(1+\tfrac{x}{n}\Big)^{-n}\leq\frac{4}{4+x^2}\in L_1(0,\infty)$. An application of dominated convergence will come in handy

Comment: @OliverDíaz That makes sense!  Are you saying that the way I used Binomial is incorrect, or is this just a nicer way to "clean up" my denominator in the integral above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}>\frac12$ for all $n$ large enough. Hence

$$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n>1+\binom{n}{1}\frac{x}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}=1+x+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}>1+\frac{1}{4}x^2$$

Hence $\Big(1+\tfrac{x}{n}\Big)^{-n}\leq\frac{4}{4+x^2}\in L_1(0,\infty)$ for all $n$ large enough.

Can you finish from this?

Comment: I may be a bit confused.... above, where you said "you still need to find a bound", isn't that what $\frac{1}{1+x+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n})x^2}$ is in my post?  If so, then that is my "$g$" in DCT, and so passing the limit inside the integral gives me $0$...
Now, with your bound, $\frac{4}{4+x^2}$, when I integrate that from $0$ to $\infty$ I get $\pi/4$, (arctangent function from $0$ to $\infty$) but that would just confirm that the integrable majorant is, indeed, an integrable majorant... that wouldn't be the answer to the integral in question, though... right?

Comment: @User7238: there are a couple of ways to  go about this. Either a direct application of DCT with the bound $\Big|\Big(1+\tfrac{x}{n}\Big)^{-n}\sin(x/n)\Big|\leq \frac{4}{4+x^2}$ or $\Big|\Big(1+\tfrac{x}{n}\Big)^{-n}\sin(x/n)\Big|\leq \frac{1}{1+x+\Big(\frac12-\frac{1}{2n}\Big)x^2}=g_n(x)$ and use a slightly different version of DCT for the sequence $g_n$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I have never seen the slightly different version of DCT that you are referencing.  I was thinking that what I had WAS a good bound.  For the actual answer, since I can put the limit inside, the integral SHOULD BE 0, right?  Not $\pi/4$?  Rather, the $\pi/4$ is just the integral OF THE BOUND, and that doesn't have to necessarily be the answer for the integral in question, right?

Comment: @User7238: The version I am referring to is: if $|f_n|\leq g_n$ and $\lim_n\int g_n=\int \lim_ng_n <\infty$, then $\lim_n\int f_n=\int \lim_nf_n$ (provided the lmits $\lim_nf_n$ and $\lim_ng_n$ exists of course. For your problem, the bound $g(x)=\frac{4}{4+x^2}$ gives the classical setting for DCT.

Comment: Okay, so let me just try to see if I am understanding this correctly: 
If I use your bound, then $\pi/4$ is the integral of that bound, so by DCT we can interchange limit and integral and get that the integral is $0$.
If I use what I have above, then I can use the version of the DCT you mention above and see that since $\lim\int g_n=\int\lim g_n<\infty$, then I can pass the limit through the integral and get $0$.  

BUT I SEE IT.. My answer still relied on $n$, whereas you found a $g$ that doesn't rely on $n$... that makes sense.

Comment: For DCT, to does not matter what the value of $\int g$ is (where $|f_n|\leq g$) , all that matters is (a) $\int g<\infty$ and (b) $\lim_nf_n=f$ exists. Then $\lim_n\int f_n=\int \lim_nf_n$. In your case, $f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-x}\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  That you, I really appreciate your time and thorough explanations... it helped immensely! :)

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$I_1(n) := \int_0^n (1 + x/n)^{-n} \sin \frac{x}{n} \mathrm{d} x$$
and
$$I_2(n) := \int_n^\infty (1 + x/n)^{-n} \sin \frac{x}{n} \mathrm{d} x.$$

Clearly, $I_1(n) \ge 0$.
Using $\sin u \le u$ for all $u\ge 0$, we have
$$I_1(n) \le \int_0^n  (1 + x/n)^{-n} \frac{x}{n} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{n(1 - n 2^{1 - n})}{(n - 1)(n - 2)}.$$
(*Note*: $\int (1 + x/n)^r \mathrm{d} x = \frac{n}{r + 1}(1 + x/n)^{r + 1} + C$ for $r \ne -1$.)

Thus, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_1(n)  = 0$.

Also, we have
$$|I_2(n)| \le \int_n^\infty (1 + x/n)^{-n} \left|\sin \frac{x}{n}\right| \mathrm{d} x
\le \int_n^\infty (1 + x/n)^{-n} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{n 2^{1 - n}}{n - 1}.$$

Thus, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_2(n)  = 0$.

The desired result follows.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac {x}{n})^{-n} = e^{-x}$

Compare your integral to $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}\sin \frac xn\ dx = \frac {n}{n^2+1}$

And show that dominated convergence allows you to interchange the limit and the integral.

Comment: You can't just take the limit in one factor but not in the other.